# How to get chat history using XMPPFramework in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

I have used [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) for one of my Chat application. I got success with the realtime chatting using this library. But when I try to fetch the history for one to one user chat and also for the group chat, then I didn't get results.

I am using the below code to fetch chat history.

```
 let detxTag:XMLElement = XMLElement(name: "message")
 detxTag.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: "mihir@gmail.com")
 detxTag.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "chat")
 detxTag.addChild(detxTag)
```

After this, I reviewed the same issue created at the mentioned repository and found the below code as a solution to get chat history.

```
let mam = XMPPMessageArchiveManagement()
mam.activate(xmppStream)
mam.addDelegate( ... )

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"

var fields = [DDXMLElement]()
fields.append(XMPPMessageArchiveManagement.field(withVar: "start", type: "text-single", andValue: formatter.string(from: startDate)))

mam.resultAutomaticPagingPageSize = 150
mam.retrieveMessageArchive(at: room.roomJID, withFields: fields, with: nil)
```

[[Referernce fo above code]](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/1166#issuecomment-616622541)

But, still, I didn't get proper success with this. Can anyone please guide me what can be changed need update to have chat history?

Comment: What response to you receive? Do you have any messages in the message archive on the server?

Comment: hi @Shreyash Mahajan if find the answer for the history retrieve if get please post your answer. I struggle on history retrieve from server ejbberd [see my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749713/issue-on-retrieve-the-xmpp-archived-message-from-ejabberd-serverchat-history)