# Issue on retrieve the XMPP archived message from ejabberd server(Chat history)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ejabberd, xmppframework

I used the following method to retrieve the chat history.

```
func getArchieveMessages(forUser user:String){
    let xmppMAM = XMPPMessageArchiveManagement.init()
    xmppMAM.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: .main)
    xmppMAM.activate(stream)
    let xmppDateString = NSDate().addingTimeInterval(-(3 * 24 * 60 * 60)).xmppDateTimeString
    var fields: [XMLElement] = []
    let start = XMPPMessageArchiveManagement.field(withVar: "end", type: nil, andValue: xmppDateString)
    fields.append(start)
     let value = DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: user)
     let child = DDXMLElement(name: "field")
     child.addChild(value)
     child.addAttribute(withName: "var", stringValue: "with")
     let set = XMPPResultSet(max: 20, before: "")
    fields.append(child)
    xmppMAM.retrieveMessageArchive(at: nil, withFields: fields, with: set)
}
```

After call this function I received the two delegates. i.e. if give 20 messages in XMPPResultSet I received 20 times **xmppStreamDidFilterStanza(_ sender: XMPPStream)** method.

```
func xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_ xmppMessageArchiveManagement: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement, didFinishReceivingMessagesWith resultSet: XMPPResultSet) {
    print("didFinishReceivingMessagesWith", resultSet)
}
    func xmppStreamDidFilterStanza(_ sender: XMPPStream) {
    debugPrint("xmppStreamDidFilterStanza")
}
```

Response in func xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_ xmppMessageArchiveManagement: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement, didFinishReceivingMessagesWith resultSet: XMPPResultSet)

```
didFinishReceivingMessagesWith <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"><count>364</count><first>1603801030936227</first><last>1603948285226175</last></set>
```

But this method is never called.

```
func xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_ xmppMessageArchiveManagement: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement, didReceiveMAMMessage message: XMPPMessage) {
  if let body = message.mamResult?.forwardedMessage{
    print("didReceiveMAMMessage", body)
  }
    print("didReceiveMAMMessage", message)
}
```

if anyone face this issue and resolved or any known the issue to solve please share your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code previously i used for message get delegate. Its totally wrong

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, willReceive message: XMPPMessage) -> XMPPMessage? {
 guard let body = (message.body?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\t", with: String.empty))?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+$", with: String.empty, options: .regularExpression) else {
   return nil
 }
 debugPrint(body)
 return message
}
```

Return the message is necessary for get history messages. previously I return nil value in guard let part

> return nil

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, willReceive message: XMPPMessage) -> XMPPMessage? {
 if let forwardedMessage = message.mamResult?.forwardedMessage{
   debugPrint(forwardedMessage)
   return message
 }
 guard let body = (message.body?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\t", with: String.empty))?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+$", with: String.empty, options: .regularExpression) else {
   return nil
 }
 debugPrint(body)
 return message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I see that you don't save xmppMAM anywhere. Try this:

```
private var xmppMAM: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement?

func getArchieveMessages(forUser user:String){
    xmppMAM = XMPPMessageArchiveManagement.init()

    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dmytryk Skorokhod thanks for your answer. I changed code like that xmppMAM declared in global . But its not working. see my instance class [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mtRtslKL16ngh8iNwW41oQrryIlkiKgN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Another suggestion: try to avoid using the main queue. I would recommend you to request MAM messages in a special queue like this: private var xmppMessageArchiveManagementQueue: DispatchQueue. Also I'm continuing reading your code to find the potential problem and will come back.

Comment: Please check whether the problem is in your "start" field. Try to retrieve messages without this field. If you will be able to retrieve them this way, we will look for the problem in the start field format (maybe the date format). The second field seems like the same I use.

Comment: Hi @Dmytryk Skorokhod if you have any sample projects  for reference.if have please provide me.

Comment: hi @Dmytryk Skorokhod thanks for your time finally I solve that issue.

Comment: @AbishekThangaraj I am not able to receive more than 20 Messages in XMPP. Do you have any solution for it?

Comment: @AbishekThangaraj Earlier it was working fine since last 4 year and it stop working suddenly.

Comment: @RushangPrajapati Please change the max value in XMPPResultSet.